# SQL Server - Database Connection Limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net, database-connection

We're having an issue with SQL server where the number of database connections hits its limit (100 is the default) and causes the website to not respond to further requests until an application pool recycle, which closes the open connections.

This is the SQL I am using to view how many connections are open per-database:

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame
ORDER BY NumberOfConnections DESC
;
```

When I see a database that has hit the limit, I recycle the database to get the site working. Before I do that however, I check to see what processes are all running. 10/10 times, I see that there are 100 connections open that are "Sleeping" and "Awaiting Command". When I check the last statement ran I see it was the code for my login page.

My question is, shouldn't these sleeping processes be getting released after a certain amount of time? They don't seem to be getting released and I believe that is why the pool eventually hits the limit and my application can't establish database connection.

Comment: Almost certainly the problem is your code. You need to close and dispose of connections when you are done with them so they can be returned to the pool.

Comment: Is it possible that you are facing a connection leak problem?

Comment: Please share your application code so we can help you fix the problem.

Comment: `Try

      ConnectionValue.Close()

      Try

        ConnectionValue.Dispose()

      Catch exSub As Exception

      End Try

      Return True

    Catch ex As Exception

      Try

        ConnectionValue.Dispose()

      Catch exSub As Exception

      End Try

      Return False

    End Try

 

    ConnectionValue = Nothing`

Comment: Tried adding the code in the comment above, but couldn't figure out how to reply to my OP with the nicely formatted view - Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, shouldn't these sleeping processes be getting released after a certain amount of time?

You've probably leaked the connections, so until they are GC'd and the finalizer closes the connection, they will remain open.  GC is not time-based, so there's no guarantee that they will be cleaned-up in a certian amount of time.

You need to find the code path where a SqlConnection is being opened, but not Close()ed or Dispose()ed and fix that code.